# PHP 7 find object that call a method

Tags: php, oop

I would like to know the best approach to check in a method, which object has called it. For instance:

```
class a
class b
class utility c (c has a method x())
```

How can I know inside x method wich class, a or b, called it?

thanks

Comment: Not that it should really matter except for debug information. Code shouldn't behave differently depending on *who called it.*

Comment: If class `c` needs to know information about the caller, consider passing it in as an argument instead

Comment: I want avoid to pass an arguments in the method. Thanks

Comment: Depending on what that argument does, you *should* probably really pass it explicitly.